# Mysql JSON_EXTRACT with double quotes in path not working

Tags: mysql, json

I have the following table def:

```
`CREATE TABLE `TestInfo` (
  `Info` json DEFAULT NULL
) ;
`
```

Am inserting two rows with json values.

```
INSERT INTO `TestInfo` (`Info`)
VALUES
    ('{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "result": {
    "summary": {
      "area": 0.0009904206008286565
    }
    }
} '
);

INSERT INTO `TestInfo` (`Info`)
VALUES
    (
'{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "result": {
    "summary": {
      "area": 0.0009904206008286565,
      "realty-society": {
        "price-min": {
          "property": "price-min",
          "min": 110000.00000000001,
          "max": 150000000,
          "average": 31184468.085106384,
          "sum": 1465670000
        }
      }
    }
  }
} '
);
```

When I run the query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$.result.summary') 
FROM TestInfo ;
```

it returns the 2 rows. This is fine.
But when I run the same query with double quotes around the path like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$."result.summary"') 
FROM TestInfo;
```

it returns the 2 rows (with the single column) as NULLs.

Ultimately I need to use double quotes for keys that have a hyphen (dash) in them.
I am using MySQL 5.7 on AWS.
Pl help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put double quotes around the whole path, just around a specific property name that contains special characters, e.g.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$.result.summary."realty-society"."price-min"')
FROM TestInfo
```

Yuor code makes `.` part of the literal property name, rather than a separator between properties. You would use it if you had:

```
"result.summary": ...
```

in the object.

Comment: Tried the query you suggested with the double quotes only around "price-min". I get 2 rows with NULLs in the result.

Comment: It worked. The right query is 'SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(Info, '$.result.summary."realty-society"."price-min"') 
FROM TestInfo;'. Thanks a lot for the tip. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This should be works if MYSQL version>=5.7

```
SELECT Info->>"$.result.summary" 
FROM TestInfo ;
```